# Vector iterator on c++

Tags: c++, vector

**I have the following:**

```
#ifndef APPSYSTEM_H
#define APPSYSTEM_H
#include "Application.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

class AppSystem{
   private:
       vector<Application> &ApplicationVector;
   public:
    AppSystem(); //AppSystem Constructor
    AppSystem(const AppSystem &); //Copy constructor
    void setApplicationVector(vector<Application> &); //Set the AppSystem's Application Vector
    vector<Application> getApplicationVector(); //Get the AppSystem's Application Vector
    void PushAppToApplicationVector(Application &) const; //Push Data to ApplicationVector
    Application &PopAppFromApplicationVector(Application &) const; //Pop Data from ApplicationVector
    vector<Application>::iterator FindAppToApplicationVector(Application &) const; //Find if Data belongs to ApplicationVector
    void DeleteAppFromApplicationVector(Application &); //Delete Data from ApplicationVector
    void ClearAllpicationVector(); //Clear all data from ApplicationVector
    virtual ~AppSystem(); //Destructor
};

#endif /* APPSYSTEM_H */

// APPSYSTEM.cpp file

//Find if Data belongs to ApplicationVector
vector<Application>::iterator AppSystem::FindAppToApplicationVector(Application &app) const{
   vector<Application>::iterator it;
   for (it = this->ApplicationVector.begin(); it = this->ApplicationVector.end(); it++){
       if (*it == app){
          return it; 
       }
}
```

**I get this error:**

```
AppSystem.cpp:56:51: error: could not convert '(it = (&((const AppSystem*)this)->AppSystem::ApplicationVector)->std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::end<Application, std::allocator<Application> >())' from 'std::vector<Application>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Application*, std::vector<Application> >}' to 'bool'
 for (it = this->ApplicationVector.begin(); it = this->ApplicationVector.end(); it++)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

On this line

```
for (it = this->ApplicationVector.begin(); it = this->ApplicationVector.end(); it++)
```

You are using the assignment equals not testing equality. Replace the test condition with `it != this->ApplicationVector.end()`

Comment: Thanks!! Yes the problem was the comparison.Final question: What should I do if I want to return other value than vector<Application>::iterator. to compare it to another method, for example NULL is error ... ?

Comment: Your suggested replacement is the same as the original code.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings thanks, that was embarrassing :)

Comment: Now it's backwards to what it should be

Comment: As for `return NULL;`... no, you can't.

Comment: Is this the right way to initialize the ApplicationVector above? AppSystem::AppSystem():ApplicationVector(*(new vector<Application>())){}

Answer (score 1):

In the condition of your for loop, you are *assigning* to `it`, instead of comparing against the result of `end()`. You need to do:

```
for (it = this->ApplicationVector.begin(); 
     it != this->ApplicationVector.end(); it++) {
       if (*it == app)
          break;
}
return it;  // return found iterator, or 'end' if not found.
```

Note the `!=` instead of `=`.

Also, it's better to return outside of the for loop, otherwise the compiler will complain that you might not be returning a value from the function.

Comment: You can't construct a `vector<Application>::iterator` from `NULL`.